# Preview tables in rmarkdown

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, preview

The preview of the tables in a rmarkdown document within R does not work anymore since the last update.
Even installing a prior version of rmarkdown and of R itself did not solve the problem.
Usually, the preview of the output is created in multiple preview windows. However, this does not work anymore. All dataframes are complied within one preview and do not look as nice as before.

What I want: A preview somehow like this where you can flip through the colums and rows:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/images/paged.png

What I get:
[No nice format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOoV3.png)

Or even:
[No nice format2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRK7r.png)

Does anyone have a solution?

I used this code:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
```

```
summary(cars)
iris
```

Thank you!

Edit: the preview magically appears if I convert the data frames to tibbles.

Comment: What is your RStudio, R and rmarkdown version?

Comment: I am using R 3.6.1 and rmarkdown version 1.15. However, I updates both to the most current version but it did not work out. Thus, I went back to the versions which were running previously.

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting is called a `paged data frame` in an HTML document in RMarkdown. You would need to add the `df_print: paged` to your YAML header.

````
---
title: "iris paged Data Frame"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r chunk2}
iris
```
````

[image]

You can control the rows printed globally with `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, rows.print=25)` inside your setup chunk.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your answer! The paged data frame is exactly what I am trying to get. Unfortunately, the output looks still the same with the edited yaml header and the knittr options are not executed, even though I did not receive an error warning. Do you have another recommendation?

Comment: Yaml is very specific, it’s indentation specific and you need to have colons exactly in the right spot. Update your question with the code you are running so we can make sure it’s exactly how it should be